# How do I suppress page headers on the blank page added between groups?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have tried to find the answer but haven't succeeded.  Any help is appreciated.

Can someone tell me how to get a BLANK page to print between each Group 1: "Employee".  COMPLETELY BLANK... NO HEADERS OR FOOTERS?

I have a very detailed Crystal Report with multiple Groups, with headers and footers as well as page headers and footers.  The end result is a report that breaks based on Group 1 "Employee".  Some Employees will have 1 page and some will have 5 or 6 pages.  I need a completely blank page in between each Group.

In Section Expert I set the Group 1 Footer to "New Page After".  This gives me a new page after each Group 1 "Employee".  But it contains the Report Headers.

I found one answer on here for a similar question that said use the formula below on the Report Header Suppress...

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Global BooleanVar finished;
finished := OnLastRecord AND NOT OnFirstRecord
```

This did prevent the Report Header from printing on the LAST BLANK PAGE and still printed the Report Header on the First Page...  BUT it still prints on each "blank" page between the groups.

I found another answer that said to try the following formula:

```
 OnLastRecord or {GROUP FIELD NAME} <> Next({GROUP FIELD NAME})
```

Here is my formula in the Suppress Formula of the Report Header:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Global BooleanVar finished;
finished := OnLastRecord AND NOT OnFirstRecord or GroupName (NAME}) <> Next(GroupName ({NAME}))
```

I also tried:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Global BooleanVar finished;
finished := GroupName ({NAME}) <> Next(GroupName ({NAME}))
```

This gives me an error message that says

> This field has no previous or next value.

FYI:  The reason for the blank page is after the report is processed we are importing it into a Document Database.  If I have a completely blank page in between each Employee the Database will split the document automatically and index each Employee's Document Separately. I'm trying to eliminate the manual document separation and indexing.

Thank you!

Comment: It is not an answer, but i'm pointing another direction to give a try. Try to use a running total field, because it has the option to evaluate a value "on group change". This may help you to avoid the "This field has no previous or next value" issue.

Comment: Thank you for the option, heringer.  If I'm understanding correctly I would use a running total field in place of the GroupName ({NAME}) in my suppress formula.  When I tried this I still received the error that "This field has no previous or next value."  Did I misunderstand what you meant?

Comment: Actually, i was thinking about get rid of the "next" function. But let me understand something first. Is "{NAME}" a field of your data source?

Comment: Yes, that is the name of the field.

Answer (score 0):

If i did understand what you want to accomplish, here it goes:

1. Create a summary to count the details for each group.
2. Create a running total field to count the details for each group.
3. Create a formula that returns true when both counters are equals.
4. Use this formula to suppress the headers and footers.
5. Leave a blank section to be in the blank page.
6. Check two options of the group footer: "new page after" and "new page before".

The explanation:

The summary (1) will always says how many details a group have (fixed).
The running total field (2) will say how many details where "printed" until a given instant.
So, when they are both equals, it means all them where printed but you are still in the group. That is the moment to suppress the header.

Ok, that was confusing. So, [here is a rpt file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11vqdsFbg7LMb6lNh2xZXQ9trX_J6qA44). Open it and change the data source for whatever database and table you can access.

EDIT:

7. Change the suppress code of header (from step 4) to:

> ```
> global booleanvar hidepagefooter;
> hidepagefooter := {@Suppress};
> {@Suppress};
> ```

8. Use the following code to suppress page footer:

> ```
> global booleanvar hidepagefooter;
> hidepagefooter;
> ```

9. Don't tell anybody i told you to use a global var. But it is Crystal Reports after all!

I did reup [the file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11vqdsFbg7LMb6lNh2xZXQ9trX_J6qA44) in case you need to take a look.

Comment: Thank you! This has gotten me very close to what I need.  I did need to change the formula suppress to a <> instead of = Count.  This works to hide the page headers for the blank page in between each group.  However it doesn't work to hide the page footer.  I assume it is because the footer is below the group that is being counted.  Any ideas?